# Empty editing description of post's first revision

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, revisions

When viewing a specific revision, the *description* entered by the user is displayed. Even if it's revision 1, the original post, with no editing description.

Depending on the site style used, this produces a visual artifact right next to *"1 of n"*:

---

[image]

---

It should maybe display *Initial revision* or just remove the container for the revision description.

Comment: Do I see a beginning recursion there? :)

Comment: @slhck No, as I clearly haven't edited this post \*cough\*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough to fix; next build, as usual. Thanks.